# vs2013 javascript document outline missing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

In this [Article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=916) they say VS2013 (WebEssentials 2013) Javascript Editor shows Document-Outline.

I´ve installed VS2013-Professional with WebEssentials but I can´t see/find the Document-Outline for the Javascript-Editor...

[image]

what am I missing?

Comment: What version of VS2013 are you running?

Comment: VS2013 - Professional

Comment: I just opened my Windows 8.1 VM on which I have VS2013 Ultimate installed and did not have Web Essentials. I downloaded the Web Essentials 2013 from [**here**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361) and after restarting VS2013 it did not add the dropdown menus at the top of the file for the functions as described in the article you linked. It does show them when opening a .cs file (it did that already before the WE anyway) but not for a .js file. I also could not find any options to enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I also was not able to get this working on my copy of VS2013 I was a little surprised.

After spending a while goggling it seems this feature was queried about in Feb 2013 on the Web Essentials forums. Web Essentials Program Manager, Mads Kristensen, responded that it was in VS2013 preview. However, on November 14th 2013 Mads then stated:

> **Mads Kristensen** (Program Manager, Web Essentials for Visual Studio)
>   commented  ·  November 14, 2013 9:01 am
>
> This was removed in VS2013 RTM
>   due to perf issues. It's coming back once the issues have been
>   resolved

[**The actual forum post**](http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3665150-javascript-function-list-dropdown)

It seems this issue has not yet been resolved.

Comment: Correct. It was removed due to performance issues from VS2013 RTM. The feature was never part of Web Essentials, but was a first-class citizen of the JS editor in VS2013